# Unit test timeout when testing Firestore

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js, firebase-cli

I have several unit tests to test different Repositories of collections in Firestore.

If I run the entire unit tests, the first two of the Firestore unit tests run fine without timeout, but the subsequent ones get timeout all the time.

If I run the failing ones each on its own (i.e. using `describe.only()`) then it runs just fine without getting any timeout.

In the `firestore-debug.log`, I see the following entries:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.643Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase emulators:exec mocha --recursive
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.643Z] CLI Version:   7.9.0
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.643Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.643Z] Node Version:  v12.13.1
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.647Z]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.647Z] 
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.658Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.658Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[info] i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore, hosting
[warn] ⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
[info] ✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
[info] i  firestore: Serving ALL traffic (including WebChannel) on http://localhost:5002
[warn] ⚠  firestore: Support for WebChannel on a separate port (5003) is DEPRECATED and will go away soon. Please use port above instead.
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.994Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.994Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:17.994Z] Starting emulator firestore with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Duser.language=en","-jar","/Users/yoda/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.10.2.jar","--host","localhost","--port",5002,"--rules","/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/firestore.rules","--functions_emulator","localhost:5001","--webchannel_port",5003],"optionalArgs":["port","webchannel_port","host","rules","functions_emulator"],"joinArgs":false}
[info] i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:19.869Z] API endpoint: http://
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:19.869Z] localhost:5002
If you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:

   export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:19.869Z] 5002

Dev App Server is now running.


[info] ✔  firestore: Emulator started at http://localhost:5002
[info] i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:5002
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:20.035Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:20.036Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 <request body omitted>
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:20.185Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:20.200Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/p0rnhub/webApps/-/config  

[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.157Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
[info] ✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
[info] ✔  hosting: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
[info] i  functions: Watching "/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions" for Cloud Functions...
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.435Z] [worker-~diagnostic~-8c5a2752-d4c3-408b-b55c-df1aba3f5987]: Assigning socketPath: /var/folders/h5/x3f6g38d1n5_wd1mrk8_ckm00000gn/T/fire_emu_67092.sock
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.435Z] [worker-~diagnostic~-8c5a2752-d4c3-408b-b55c-df1aba3f5987]: BUSY
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.804Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Functions runtime initialized. {"cwd":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions","node_version":"12.13.1"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.806Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Disabled runtime features: undefined
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.810Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Resolved module firebase-admin {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"8.8.0","resolution":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:21.812Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.3.0","resolution":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/index.js"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.124Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Found google-gax at /Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.js
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.124Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Outgoing network have been stubbed. [{"name":"http","status":"mocked"},{"name":"http","status":"mocked"},{"name":"https","status":"mocked"},{"name":"https","status":"mocked"},{"name":"net","status":"mocked"},{"name":"google-gax","status":"mocked"}]
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.178Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Checked functions.config() {"config":{}}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.179Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.3.0","resolution":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/index.js"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.180Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Resolved module firebase-admin {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"8.8.0","resolution":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.180Z] [runtime-status] [67092] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.3.0","resolution":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/index.js"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.232Z] [runtime-status] [67092] firebase-admin has been stubbed. {"adminResolution":{"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"8.8.0","resolution":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js"}}
[info] ✔  functions[auth]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/p0rnhub/us-central1/auth).
[info] ✔  functions[token]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/p0rnhub/us-central1/token).
[info] ✔  functions[login]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/p0rnhub/us-central1/login).
[info] ✔  functions[start]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/p0rnhub/us-central1/start).
[info] ✔  functions[stop]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/p0rnhub/us-central1/stop).
[info] ✔  functions[list]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/p0rnhub/us-central1/list).
[info] i  Running script: mocha --recursive
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.252Z] Running mocha --recursive with environment {"npm_config_save_dev":"","npm_config_legacy_bundling":"","npm_config_dry_run":"","npm_config_viewer":"man","npm_config_only":"","npm_config_commit_hooks":"true","npm_config_browser":"","npm_config_also":"","npm_config_sign_git_commit":"","npm_config_rollback":"true","TERM_PROGRAM":"Apple_Terminal","NODE":"/usr/local/bin/node","npm_config_usage":"","npm_config_audit":"true","INIT_CWD":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions","npm_package_devDependencies_sinon":"^7.5.0","npm_config_globalignorefile":"/usr/local/etc/npmignore","npm_package_devDependencies_mocha":"^6.2.2","TERM":"xterm-256color","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","npm_config_shell":"/bin/zsh","npm_config_maxsockets":"50","npm_config_init_author_url":"","npm_config_shrinkwrap":"true","npm_config_parseable":"","npm_config_metrics_registry":"https://registry.npmjs.org/","TMPDIR":"/var/folders/h5/x3f6g38d1n5_wd1mrk8_ckm00000gn/T/","npm_config_timing":"","npm_config_init_license":"ISC","npm_config_if_present":"","TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION":"433","npm_config_sign_git_tag":"","npm_config_init_author_email":"","npm_config_cache_max":"Infinity","npm_package_dependencies_uuid":"^3.3.3","npm_config_preid":"","npm_config_long":"","npm_config_local_address":"","npm_config_git_tag_version":"true","npm_config_cert":"","TERM_SESSION_ID":"AD305AB7-88B6-4E8E-9681-273EEB25429A","npm_config_registry":"https://registry.npmjs.org/","npm_config_noproxy":"","npm_config_fetch_retries":"2","npm_package_private":"true","npm_config_versions":"","npm_config_message":"%s","npm_config_key":"","npm_package_description":"Cloud Functions for Firebase","USER":"yoda","npm_package_scripts_deploy":"firebase deploy --only functions","npm_config_globalconfig":"/usr/local/etc/npmrc","npm_package_scripts_shell":"firebase functions:shell","npm_config_prefer_online":"","npm_config_logs_max":"10","npm_config_always_auth":"","SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.sLVgtsWI6z/Listeners","__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING":"0x1F5:0x0:0x0","npm_execpath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js","npm_config_global_style":"","npm_config_cache_lock_retries":"10","npm_package_dependencies_firebase_functions":"^3.3.0","npm_config_update_notifier":"true","npm_config_cafile":"","npm_config_heading":"npm","npm_config_audit_level":"low","npm_config_searchlimit":"20","npm_config_read_only":"","npm_config_offline":"","npm_config_fetch_retry_mintimeout":"10000","npm_config_json":"","npm_config_access":"","npm_config_argv":"{\"remain\":[],\"cooked\":[\"test\"],\"original\":[\"test\"]}","PATH":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin","npm_config_allow_same_version":"","npm_config_https_proxy":"","npm_config_engine_strict":"","npm_config_description":"true","_":"/usr/local/bin/firebase","LaunchInstanceID":"486CA774-9DDE-42B4-A90D-EB3553FE7181","npm_config_userconfig":"/Users/yoda/.npmrc","npm_config_init_module":"/Users/yoda/.npm-init.js","npm_config_cidr":"","PWD":"/Users/yoda/Projects/p0rnhub/service/functions","npm_config_user":"","npm_config_node_version":"12.13.1","npm_lifecycle_event":"test","npm_config_save":"true","npm_config_ignore_prepublish":"","npm_config_editor":"vi","npm_config_auth_type":"legacy","npm_package_name":"functions","npm_config_tag":"latest","npm_config_script_shell":"","npm_config_progress":"true","npm_config_global":"","npm_config_before":"","npm_package_scripts_start":"npm run shell","npm_config_searchstaleness":"900","npm_config_optional":"true","npm_config_ham_it_up":"","XPC_FLAGS":"0x0","npm_config_save_prod":"","npm_config_force":"","npm_config_bin_links":"true","npm_config_searchopts":"","npm_package_engines_node":"8","npm_config_node_gyp":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js","npm_config_depth":"Infinity","npm_config_sso_poll_frequency":"500","npm_config_rebuild_bundle":"true","npm_package_version":"","XPC_SERVICE_NAME":"0","npm_config_unicode":"true","HOME":"/Users/yoda","SHLVL":"2","npm_config_fetch_retry_maxtimeout":"60000","npm_package_scripts_test":"firebase emulators:exec \"mocha --recursive\"","npm_config_tag_version_prefix":"v","npm_config_strict_ssl":"true","npm_config_sso_type":"oauth","npm_config_scripts_prepend_node_path":"warn-only","npm_config_save_prefix":"^","npm_config_loglevel":"notice","npm_config_ca":"","npm_package_scripts_serve":"firebase serve --only functions","npm_config_save_exact":"","npm_config_group":"20","npm_config_fetch_retry_factor":"10","npm_config_dev":"","npm_package_devDependencies_firebase_functions_test":"^0.1.7","npm_config_version":"","npm_config_prefer_offline":"","npm_config_cache_lock_stale":"60000","npm_package_devDependencies__firebase_testing":"^0.12.3","npm_config_otp":"","npm_config_cache_min":"10","npm_config_searchexclude":"","npm_config_cache":"/Users/yoda/.npm","npm_package_dependencies_base64url":"^3.0.1","npm_package_scripts_logs":"firebase functions:log","LOGNAME":"yoda","npm_lifecycle_script":"firebase emulators:exec \"mocha --recursive\"","npm_config_color":"true","npm_config_proxy":"","npm_config_package_lock":"true","npm_package_dependencies_build_url":"^1.3.3","LC_CTYPE":"UTF-8","npm_config_package_lock_only":"","npm_config_fund":"true","npm_config_save_optional":"","npm_config_ignore_scripts":"","npm_config_user_agent":"npm/6.13.4 node/v12.13.1 darwin x64","npm_config_cache_lock_wait":"10000","npm_config_production":"","npm_config_send_metrics":"","npm_config_save_bundle":"","npm_config_umask":"0022","npm_config_node_options":"","npm_config_init_version":"1.0.0","npm_config_init_author_name":"","npm_config_git":"git","npm_config_scope":"","SECURITYSESSIONID":"186a8","npm_config_unsafe_perm":"true","npm_config_tmp":"/var/folders/h5/x3f6g38d1n5_wd1mrk8_ckm00000gn/T","npm_config_onload_script":"","npm_package_dependencies_firebase_admin":"^8.8.0","npm_node_execpath":"/usr/local/bin/node","npm_config_prefix":"/usr/local","npm_config_link":"","npm_config_format_package_lock":"true","FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST":"localhost:5002","FIREBASE_FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_ADDRESS":"localhost:5002"}
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.263Z] [worker-~diagnostic~-8c5a2752-d4c3-408b-b55c-df1aba3f5987]: exited
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:22.263Z] [worker-~diagnostic~-8c5a2752-d4c3-408b-b55c-df1aba3f5987]: FINISHED
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:23.385Z] Dec 25, 2019 11:29:23 AM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected HTTP/2 connection.

[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:24.429Z] Dec 25, 2019 11:29:24 AM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected HTTP/2 connection.

[warn] ⚠  Script exited unsuccessfully (code 4)
[info] i  Shutting down emulators.
[info] i  Stopping functions emulator
[info] i  Stopping firestore emulator
[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:34.479Z] *** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down

[debug] [2019-12-25T04:29:34.482Z] *** server shut down

[info] i  Stopping hosting emulator
[error] 
[error] Error: Script "mocha --recursive" exited with code 4
```

Here's how I setup each Firestore unit test:

```
const assert = require("assert")
const firebase = require("@firebase/testing")
const { SampleRepository } = require("./SampleRepository")

const projectId = "a-project-id"
const app = firebase.initializeAdminApp({ projectId })

describe("SampleRepository", () => {
    var db
    var repository

    before(async () => {
        db = app.firestore()
        repository = new SampleRepository(db)
    })

    afterEach(async () => {
        await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId })
    })

    after(async () => {
        await db.terminate()
    })

    describe("firstMethod", () => {
        it("use case 1", async () => {
            // Do some testing here.
        })

        it("use case 2", async () => {
            // Do some testing here.
        })
    })

    describe("secondMethod", () => {
        it("use case 1", async () => {
            // Do some testing here.
        })
    })
})
```

I setup the `npm test` command to invoke this: `firebase emulators:exec \"mocha --recursive\"`.

At this point, I am pretty clueless what causes this but I suspect it's a problem in the Firestore emulator or something? And I don't know what `code 4` means in: `Script exited unsuccessfully (code 4)`.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** Now I know what the `code 4` means. It means that I have 4 failing tests.

Comment: Hmmm... If Firestore is part of the test, that's not unit testing, by definition.